# Hooking getchar() is very easy, but how to how to hook std::cin?

Tags: c++, hook, cin

Hooking `getchar()` is very easy, but how to how to hook `std::cin`?

Here is the method to hook `getchar()`:

Using a shared library which has a function named getchar
(i.e `int getchar(void){printf("test\n");}`).

Then start the target program with `PRE_LOAD_PATH` macro.

Could anybody shed some light on this question?
It would be better if you could give a simple implementation.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by hooking `cin`? Did you try any code so far? This seems a bit too vague or recommendation-/example-like to be on-topic.

Comment: @underscore_d In fact, I have no idea how to achieve this goal. I only know that I have to overload `std::cin`(i.e give an implementation by myself).

Comment: Did have you try to overload the operator like that : istream& operator >> (istream &in,  YourClass& c) { ... }

Comment: @mm98 Could you please explain that in more detail?  What's the function of the class named `YourClass`? I mean what functions should I provide for this class?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. In the case of your own created class (in my comment : YourClass), you can do like this : https://medium.com/@nonuruzun/overloading-input-output-operators-in-c-a2a74c5dda8a

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. A possible solution is changing `std::cin`'s `rdbuf` to a custom one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good news, it's reopened now!